# Are there any additional steps required to setup an AWS CloudFront with an S3 Bucket besides adding the Bucket Policy and origin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to deploy my PERN app on AWS. I already have the Node.js backend server running in the background with PM2 on an EC2 instance, the postgres database on and RDS instance, and the frontend is working fine on the S3 bucket. However, I am struggling to get my CloudFront distribution to fetch data from the backend. The S3 bucket fetches data just fine. I set up the origin via OAC settings and added the bucket policy information for the CloudFront into the S3 bucket. I also ensured that the CloudFront is referring to the correct S3 Bucket origin. Additionally, I make the S3 objects public using ACL and enabled Static website hosting.

Here's the Bucket Policy I added:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "<S3 Bucket Resource>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "<CloudFront Distribution>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's some of the configuration on my CloudFront:

-- Origins:

**Origin name**: -S3 Bucket name- | **Origin domain**: -S3 Bucket domain- | **Origin path**: __
| **Origin type**: S3

-- Behaviors:

**Precedence**: 0 | **Path pattern**: Default (*) | **Origin or origin group**: -S3 bucket- | **Viewer protocol policy**: HTTP and HTTPS | **Cache policy name**: Managed-CachingOptimized

-- Error pages:

**HTTP error code**: 403 | **Minimum TTL (sec)**: 10 | **Response page path**: /index.html | **HTTP response code**: 200

I've also added the following inbound rules to my EC2 instance's security group:

**Type**: Custom TCP | **Protocol**: TCP | **Port range**: 3001 | **Source**: Custom | 0.0.0.0/0

**Type**: HTTPS | **Protocol**: TCP | **Port range**: 443 | **Source**: Custom | 0.0.0.0/0

**Type**: All traffic | **Protocol**: All | **Port range**: All | **Source**: Custom | 0.0.0.0/0

**Type**: SSH | **Protocol**: TCP | **Port range**: 22 | **Source**: Custom | 0.0.0.0/0

**Type**: All TCP | **Protocol**: TCP | **Port range**: 0 - 65535 | **Source**: Custom | 0.0.0.0/0

**Type**: HTTP | **Protocol**: TCP | **Port range**: 80 | **Source**: Custom | 0.0.0.0/0

I can always just use the Bucket website endpoint, but I would like to implement CloudFront to increase speed and performance.

Comment: You should change the origin type from `s3` to `custom` and use the bucket static web hosting endpoint as origin. Read [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/) for more details.

Comment: I tried changing it to custom, but still not reaching the backend

Comment: @jellycsc - if you configure it as a custom origin, that means that people will be able to go to S3 directly. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html for what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @jason_coder - my guess is that the path that you're providing to the origin doesn't exist. If you just give `s3:GetObject` permission, then an incorrect path is reported as a 403, not a 404 (see https://blog.kdgregory.com/2020/03/s3-troubleshooting-when-403-is-really.html). To debug, turn on CloudFront logging and S3 bucket logging, and compare the path given to CloudFront to the path that it requests from S3. Your EC2 instance should not be involved (so no need to provide details about its security group).